# Failing to add site extension to azure web app through arm template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to install a site extension into my web app automatically with an ARM template.

The code for the site extension is as followed:

```
 {
                         "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
                          "name": "phpMyAdmin",
                          "type": "siteextensions",
                          "dependsOn": [
                            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppPortalName'))]",
                          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites/config', variables('webAppPortalName'), 'web')]"
                          ],
                          "properties": {
                          }
```

In my properties of my  web site Resources i declared:

```
 "properties":{  
                            "RepoUrl":"https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/wordpress-azure",
                              "branch":"linux-appservice",
                              "IsManualIntegration":true,
                               "appSettings": [
                                { "Name": "SCM_SITEEXTENSIONS_FEED_URL", "Value": "http://www.siteextensions.net/api/v2/" }
                              ]
                           }
```

But as i deploy my arm template I am getting this error and i can't seem to find why the deploy failed:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 15:15:43 - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions 'website-webapp/phpMyAdmin' failed with message '{
  "id": "/subscriptions/a6e10cb0-79e5-4b68-af13-d17fc5f7505a/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/website-webapp/siteextensions/phpMyAdmin",
  "name": "bmtwebsite-webapp/phpMyAdmin",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions",
  "location": "West Europe",
  "properties": {
    "id": "phpMyAdmin",
    "title": null,
    "type": "Gallery",
    "summary": null,
    "description": null,
    "version": null,
    "extension_url": null,
    "project_url": null,
    "icon_url": null,
    "license_url": null,
    "feed_url": null,
    "authors": null,
    "installer_command_line_params": null,
    "published_date_time": null,
    "download_count": 0,
    "local_is_latest_version": null,
    "local_path": null,
    "installed_date_time": null,
    "provisioningState": "Failed",
    "comment": "'phpMyAdmin' not found."
  }
}'
```

After this big error message i get this error which is a more general one i think.

```
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "xxxxxxxxxx" ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 15:17:46 - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debu
g for usage details.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "xxxxxxxxxxx" ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

Anyone tried to add site extensions with ARM templates and knows what my error seems to be , or can guide me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your branch name being `linux-appservice`, I assume you are trying to do this in a Linux App Service. If so, be aware that Linux Apps do not support site extensions.